# PHP How to print a single value from this Array?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have an Array like this one:

> Array ( [0] => a:39:{s:2:"id";s:6:"703981";s:4:"name";s:10:"Bilton Apt";s:7:"address";s:25:"Hart Blvd, Paradise Acres";s:3:"zip";s:2:"PO";s:10:"city_hotel";s:11:"Montego ....etc...

And i want to print in the page the "name" value so i wrote these two lines of code:

```
 $item = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ihfc_hotel'); 
 echo $item['name'];
```

But when i load the page i receive this error:

Notice: Undefined index: name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp_test_csv/wp-content/themes/twenty....etc

i tried with other solutions like:

```
echo $item[0]['name']; or echo $item[0]->['name']:
```

But none works

Some one can help me?

Comment: You're going to need an [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) somewhere.

Comment: Your array contains serialized values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unserialize the array, as told in the comments:

```
$ar = unserialize($item[0]);
echo $ar['name'];
```

You can put it in a loop to get all values in a multi dimensional array:

```
foreach($item as $key=>$value){
    $ar[$key] = unserialize($value);
}
```

and then access it:

```
echo $ar[0]['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Stirling and u_mulder said, your array contains a serialized value and the only one shown in your example is index 0.
So due the fact that your example string is cut short with `....etc...` I can only answer to what is known.

```
$data = unserialize($item[0]);
print_r($data);

echo $data['name'] // Bilton Apt
```

This should do that trick.

Comment: Thanks this is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
<?php 

 $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ihfc_hotel', true); 
 echo $name;
```

**Otherwise**

```
<?php 

 $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ihfc_hotel', true); 
 $data = unserialize($data);

 var_dump($data);
 var_dump($data['name']);
```

Comment: According to the wordpress manual of [get_post_data()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) `$single` is set to false, as *presumably* there are more values.